# Await image.onload in for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, promise, async-await

I'm trying to convert an array of base64 encoded PNGs (imported via `require()`ing the file asset) into an RGBA array.  The method I'm using is writing the base64 string to an image element and the reading the data from `getImageData()` on the image's context.

However I'm getting royally confused by the interaction between the `image.onload` event listener and Promises and the for loop.

```
      async function afterImageLoad(src) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          const signCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
          const signContext = signCanvas.getContext("2d")
          const signImage = new Image(108, 108);

          signImage.onload = async () => {
            signImage.decode().then(() => {
              resolve(signContext.getImageData(0, 0, 108, 108));
            })
          }
          signImage.src = src;
        })
      }

      for (let i = 0; i < this.table.length; i++) {

        let signImageSrc = this.table[i].imageURL; // The base64 string
        let signImageData = await afterImageLoad(signImageSrc) // I want the for-loop to pause here

        let diff = pixelmatch(
            drawingPixelData.data,
            signImageData.data,
            diffContext.data,
            108,
            108,
        ); // right now this is always 0, because the signImageData is not loaded.
```

Comment: you are trying to use await outside an async function?

Comment: The function wrapping all of these commands is an async function.  I don't mind how it shakes out, I just want to wait for each image to load before I run `pixelmatch()`.

Comment: `afterImageLoad` doesn't need to be `async`, neither does `signImage.onload` since you never `await` ... but you can only `await someAsyncValue` inside a function that is tagged `async` ... i.e. you've used `async` where you didn't need to, and haven't used `async` where you DO need to

Comment: Thanks, yeah I figured I was using them wrong.  My question is I guess more about how to await the `image.onload` i.e. I only want computation to proceed once the `image.onload` is complete so that I can run `getImageData()` successfully.

Comment: the `signCanvas` and `signContext` in `afterImageLoad` are a mystery ... do you expect the image data to somehow "appear" in that canvas? because `signImage` is never added to the canvas, so `signContext.getImageData` will contain data from a blank canvas context

Comment: I thought I had to create an Image, Canvas, and Context in order to load the base64 PNG data in, so that when I ran `getImageData()` I'd get a RGBA Array.